# Twilio Ougoing Voice Call : Token does not allow outgoing calls on first attempt

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

I have recently started experiencing peculiar behaviour trying to initiate an outgoing phone call Browser -> Phone.

Every time I refresh the browser, my initial call to `Twilio.Device.connect(phonecallParams)` results in an error:

`Received an error from the gateway: {code: 31002, connection: Connection, message: "Token does not allow outgoing calls."}`.

If I make a second call to `Twilio.Device.connect(phonecallParams)`, it works.
Also every subsequent call works.   But if I refresh the browser then the first call fails again.

It used to work first time, every time.   But I last tested this weeks ago.
Now it fails first time, every time.

With the first, failed call:

1. I get call my back-end to get a token
2. I return the token to the JS method
3. I call Twilio.Device.connect(phonecallParams)
4. I get the error message.
5. Nothing else happens.   There is no attempt to call my TwiML handler.

With the second, successful call:

1. I get call my back-end to get a token
2. I return the token to the JS method
3. I call Twilio.Device.connect(phonecallParams)
4. My backend method that handles TwiML is called
5. Call is initiated.

In both cases:

- the token construction is identical the same method which creates the token the same way (and includes `new OutgoingClientScope(_twilioAccount.TwiMLApplicationSid)`)
- the phonecallParams are identical

Would anyone have a clue as to what could be going on??

Comment: That is weird. Can you share the code that generates the token? Also, can you inspect an example token in https://jwt.io and ensure the outgoing application sid is being set on the first token?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this turned out to be one of those silly things...

I was calling Twilio.Device.connect() immediately / too soon after requesting my token - the same trigger that requested the token also triggered  Twilio.Device.connect().

I now request my outgoing phone token when my page loads, and by the time the user wants to initiate the call the token has been completely set up, wherever it needs to be.